# RegEx to match character followed or preceded by another character or both but not neither

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a hyphen if it is preceded or followed by spaces or both but not a standalone hyphen. While multiple pipes will solve this issue (similar to a question already asked but not the same), I wanted to know if there exists a direct solution.

Eg. I want to match (assume `.` to be a space for formatting) `.-.` or `.-` or `-.` but not just `-`.

current expression:

```py
/ *- */g
```

matches all of these.

Is there a way to have 1 or more but for the aggregate as in at least one space before or after the hyphen?

Edit: more context

I'm processing multiple expressions:

```py
aln = re.compile(r'[^ \-a-zA-Z0-9]+')  # matches non space or - or alphanumeric characters
spc = re.compile(' +')  # matches one or more spaces

url_data = song + '-' + artist
url_data = re.sub(aln, '', url_data)  # remove punctuation and other characters
url_data = re.sub(spc, '-', url_data)  # substitute one or more spaces to -
```

Eg. if song is `ABC, XYZ` and artist is `PQR` then finally I get `PQR-ABC-XYZ`.

However if the song is of the form `, ABC ,` and artist `PQR` then I get `PQR--ABC-` while I want `PQR-ABC`.

If I update spc to `*- *| +` then in normal cases (first example) it would redundantly match a hyphen and substitute it with a hyphen only which I'm trying to improve upon.

Comment: *"While multiple pipes will solve this issue"*: no, only one pipe.

Comment: Try: `(\s\-|\-\s)`

Comment: Maybe `\s?-\s|\s-\s?` will do. Or `\s*-\s+|\s+-\s*`

Comment: @alfasin that wouldn't match ' - ' as a single unit but would leave a space.

Comment: @aadibajpai it will match it not as a single unit but it will match it because ' - ' is a specific case of ' -'. Is that a problem? If yes - why?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte right, actually this regex was itself a part of a pipe where I am using it so I wrote it as multiple sorry!

Comment: @alfasin I'm subbing the whole thing so an extra space creates a problem in later use.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that works well, I'm not much experienced but does regex allow some way to implement this without piping? Not being picky, just curious.

Comment: @aadibajpai: it may be interesting to show the full pattern/problem to give a context to your question. (*this way you will perhaps obtain something closer to your needs*)

Comment: You have to use piping as it represents "or" which is the exact thing you are expressing when you have multiple matching criteria.

Comment: So do: `(\s-\s|\s-|-\s)` this way it'll try to match `' - '` first before it tries the others. See: https://regex101.com/r/hdXsZO/1

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte okay, I updated the question. Let me know if I can improve more on it.

Comment: Try `"-".join(re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+', url_data))`. The pattern may be `r'[^\W_]+'` or - if the underscores in the results are OK - just `r'\w+'`

Comment: Yes, but note that with the new desired format, you are not able to know where starts the song name and where stops the artist name if this one contains an hyphen: Cersei-Lannister-valar-morghulis

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I didn't do that because it doesn't address spaces around the hyphen in the middle but just the ones leading/trailing in url_data

Comment: For not retaining multiple hyphens you could change `re.compile(' +')` to `re.compile('[ -]+')` This will ensure your space(s) and multiple hyphens will be reduced to a single hyphen. But not sure whether you want to retain multiple hyphens within songname intact. If not then your current strategy needs to change and you should first apply cleaning independently to both songname and artist separately and then append them with a hyphen

Comment: And why you don't use url encoding like 'Bach-die kunst der fuge' => 'Bach-die%20kunst%20der%20fuge' ?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I tested the current approach as well as independently stripping both song and artist and then joining them by timing them both with timeit. Current approach is faster so I'm thinking of just keeping the redundancy.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte the URL I'm formatting uses hyphen b/w words as it is

Comment: The problem is that if you have an artist ABC with a song DEF GHI and an artist ABC DEF with a song GHI, you obtain the same url for two different artists/songs. In other words, it's better to choose a separator between the artist and the song that isn't used in the artist name or in the song name.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte that's not in my hand, I'm trying to conform to a given URL given just the song and artist. Full context, https://github.com/SwagLyrics/SwagLyrics-For-Spotify/blob/dev/swaglyrics/cli.py

Answer (score 0):

`Eg. I want to match (assume . to be a space for formatting) .-. or .- or -. but not just -`

You use an assertion for one condition, then a non assertion template for the remaining conditions.
This way you don't need alternations in this case.

For your *dot* analogy, it is simply this
`(?=[.-]*\.)\.*-\.*`

https://regex101.com/r/ivtl8z/1

Substituting a space for the dot, yields this  (space framed in class for visual affect)
`(?=[ -]*[ ])[ ]*-[ ]*`

otherwise this (framed as a string)

```
regex = '(?=[ -]* ) *- *'
```